# Can I introspect the name of the main.main package?

Tags: module, go, package, introspection

This is a fairly niche problem, but I'm currently trying to write a conventions-based settings storage library with golang. It would be a great API boon if I could programmatically determine the running package name that wants to store something (eg `"github.net/author/projectname/pkg"`) calling my library function.

With Python a similar thing could be achieved with the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module, or even with `__main__.__file__` and a look at the file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get similar information if you use the following functions:

- [`runtime.Caller`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller)
- [`runtime.FuncForPC`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#FuncForPC)

The code may look like this:

```
pc, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
if !ok { /*failed*/ }
println(pc, file, line, ok)

f := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
if f == nil { /*failed*/ }
println(f.Name())
```

If I put the above code (with the 1st line changed into `runtime.Caller(0)`) into a (randomly chosen) Go library which I have installed in `GOROOT`, it prints:

```
134626026 /tmp/go-build223663414/github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk/_obj/gtk.cgo1.go -4585 true
github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk.Init
```

Or it prints:

```
134515752 /home/user/go/src/github.com/mattn/go-gtk/example/event/event.go 12 true
main.main
```

The filename on the 1st line, and the 2nd line, seem to contain the information you are looking for.

There are two problems:

- It may give incorrect result if functions are automatically inlined by the compiler
- For any function `F` defined in package `main`, the function name is just `main.F`. For example, if `runtime.Caller(0)` is called from `main()`, the function name is `main.main` even if the `main()` function is defined in a Go file found in `GOROOT/src/github.com/mattn/go-gtk/...`. In this case, the output from `runtime.Caller` is more useful than the output from `runtime.FuncForPC`.